# Connecting to imap.google with SSL

Tags: c++, openssl

I`m trying to make an email client but it doesn't work :/ Im trying to connect to google imap with SSL (without SSL i can make it) Code:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "openssl/ssl.h"
#include "iostream"
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#define BUFSIZE 1024
char buf[BUFSIZE]; 
char *msg;
WSADATA wsda;
int     sock;
struct hostent *host;
struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
short int       s_port = 993;
const char      *s_ipaddr = "74.125.77.109";
 int SSL_library_init();
 SSL_METHOD *meth;
 int main () {
SSL_load_error_strings();  
    SSL_library_init();
    //RAND_seed(buf, BUFSIZE);

    SSL_CTX *sslContext = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method()); 
    if (sslContext == NULL)
    { 
        cout << "err\n";
    }

    SSL *sslConnection = SSL_new(sslContext); 
    if(sslConnection == NULL) 
    { 
        cout << "err\n";
    }




    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsda);

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP);

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(s_port);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(s_ipaddr);

    if(server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr == INADDR_NONE)
    {
        host = NULL;
        host = gethostbyname(s_ipaddr);
        if(host == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
        memcpy(&server_addr.sin_addr, host->h_addr_list[0], host->h_length);
    }

    connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));


    SSL_set_fd(sslConnection, sock);

    SSL_connect(sslConnection);
    cout << "Connecting:\n";

    SSL_read(sslConnection, buf, sizeof(buf)-1); 
    cout << buf << "\n";

    cout << "Logging-in:\n";
    msg = "a1 login emailapp123@gmail.com PASS\n";
    SSL_write(sslConnection, msg, strlen(msg));

    SSL_read(sslConnection, buf, sizeof(buf)-1); 
    cout << buf << "\n";

    cout << "INBOX\n";

    msg = "a2 SELECT INBOX\n";
    SSL_write(sslConnection, msg, strlen(msg));
    SSL_read(sslConnection, buf, sizeof(buf)-1);
    cout << buf << "\n";
    system("pause");
 }
```

And thats what i receive:

> Connecting:
>   * OK Gimap ready for requests from 195.150.156.162 y48if37710eei.45
>
> Logging-in:
>   * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT LITERAL+ IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN
>   X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE
>   a1 OK emailapp123@gmail.com authenticated (Success)
>
> INBOX

What should I do to make the connection right?
Thanks for every advice :-)
Chris

Comment: It seems to have authenticated.  What's the problem?

Comment: It doesn't respond to my "a2 SELECT INBOX\n" request. Im not even sure if its a ssl connection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to terminate all commands sent to an imap server with both a carriage return and a line feed. Send `a2 SELECT INBOX\r\n` and it should work.

Comment: WOW! Its working! Thanks, man! I thought that i tried that way but i was wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

seems you are not terminating line command with \r\n. Please refer RFC

http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3501.html

Comment: Why are you repeating answers?  This question was already answered sufficiently, with the *same* answer, 3 years earlier.